# Adding a stdClass Object in a data structure

Tags: php, data-structures, stdclass

```php
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'zone1' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => '123',
       'owner' => '234',
       ...
    )),
```

My basics are a bit shot, so I'm having trouble with this... I need to create the above structure, but I'm not sure how to...

Comment: `stdClass` doesn't have a `__set_state()` method.

Comment: @Daniel Egeberg: You're right, it doesn't have that method. It's just how objects are exported (which makes little sense, for stdClass)  `var_export((object)array('zone1'=>array((object)array('id'=>'123','owner'=>'234'))));`

Answer (score 9):

```
$a = new stdclass;
$a->zone1 = array();
$a->zone1[0] = new stdclass;
$a->zone1[0]->id = "123";
$a->zone1[0]->owner = "234";
```

Alternatively, relying upon the fact that arrays are converted to stdClass objects when casted into objects:

```
$a = (object) array(
    "zone1" => array(
       (object) array("id" => "123", "owner" => "234"),
    ),
);
```

For this, `var_export` gives:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'zone1' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => '123',
       'owner' => '234',
    )),
  ),
))
```

Note that, has Daniel has pointed out, `stdClass` doesn't actually have a `__set_state` method. I supposed you were just exemplifying the structure of the variable by giving the output of `var_export`. Serialization should be done with `serialize` instead.